# Material matInput ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am trying to build a form field component like in the [Angular Dynamic Form example](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form#dynamic-forms).

Everything works quite well until I need to switch the input components between an input and a select. When validation is added I receive the following error

`ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ng-untouched: null'. Current value: 'ng-untouched: mat-error-0'.`

Without the `ngSwitch` and only the `matInput` I never get the error.

How do I solve the issue?

Here is the component.

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

export class FieldOptions {
  name: string;
  label: string;
  type: string;
  required: boolean;
  readOnly: boolean;
  maxLength: number;
  choices?: {key: string, value: string}[] = [];
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-field',
  templateUrl: './field.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./field.component.scss']
})
export class FieldComponent {
  @Input() fieldOption: FieldOptions;
  @Input() form: FormGroup;

  constructor() { }

  protected findFieldControl(): AbstractControl {
    return this.form.get(this.fieldOption.name);
  }

  fieldHasErrors(): boolean {
    const control = this.findFieldControl();
    if (control && control.touched && control.errors) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  fieldErrors(): FormErrors {
    const control = this.findFieldControl();
    if (this.fieldHasErrors()) {
      return control.errors;
    } else {
      return {};
    }
  }

}
```

HTML

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
  <mat-form-field [ngSwitch]="fieldOption.type">
    <input matInput *ngSwitchCase="'input'" placeholder="{{fieldOption.label}}" [formControlName]="fieldOption.name">
    <mat-select *ngSwitchCase="'choice'" placeholder="{{fieldOption.label}}" [formControlName]="fieldOption.name">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let choice of fieldOption.choices" [value]="choice.value">
        {{choice['display_name']}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
    <mat-error *ngIf="fieldErrors()['required']">
      This field is required.
    </mat-error>
    <mat-error *ngIf="fieldErrors()['maxlength']">
      Should be {{fieldOption.maxLength}} characters or less.
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you try switching out the entire mat-form-field rather than the input and select. You might also be able to use ng-container and ng-template to re-use the error elements instead of duplicating them.  Something like:

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
  <ng-container [ngSwitch]="fieldOption.type">
    <mat-form-field *ngSwitchCase="'input'">
      <input matInput placeholder="{{fieldOption.label}}" [formControlName]="fieldOption.name">
      <mat-error *ngIf="fieldErrors()['required']">
        This field is required.
      </mat-error>
      <mat-error *ngIf="fieldErrors()['maxlength']">
        Should be {{fieldOption.maxLength}} characters or less.
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field *ngSwitchCase="'choice'">
      <mat-select placeholder="{{fieldOption.label}}" [formControlName]="fieldOption.name">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let choice of fieldOption.choices" [value]="choice.value">
          {{choice['display_name']}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
      <mat-error *ngIf="fieldErrors()['required']">
        This field is required.
      </mat-error>
      <mat-error *ngIf="fieldErrors()['maxlength']">
        Should be {{fieldOption.maxLength}} characters or less.
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is really difficult to use ng-container or ng-template with the mat-errors. https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/6625 .